# Making a powershell script download files quicker from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, file, amazon-s3, download

We have a third party service that uploads files to a certain s3 bucket in our account. The amount varies and it can sometimes reach a few hundred files in a few minutes. Also, each time a file is received we update an SQS queue. We need to do three things for each file that we receive in this bucket:

1. Download it to a local windows server
2. Move it to a folder inside the bucket called "Done"
3. Remove the file from the root of the bucket

In order to do this and not have duplicates, we are using the following script that uses a list and runs every 10 minutes:

```
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
$date = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss"
Start-Transcript -path C:\temp\log_$date.txt -append

Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName profile
Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region eu-west-1

$BucketName = “example-bucket”
$SqsURL = ”https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/example-bucket”
$BucketRootObjects = Get-S3Object -BucketName $BucketName 
Clear-SQSQueue -QueueUrl $SqsURL -Force
$BucketDirsToSync = @()
foreach ($BucketObject in $BucketRootObjects) {
if($BucketObject.Key.contains(“Done/”))
{continue}
$BucketDirsToSync += $BucketObject.Key
}
foreach( $dirname in $BucketDirsToSync){
Copy-S3Object -BucketName $BucketName -Key $dirname -LocalFile \\winserver\files\$dirname
}
Foreach( $dirname in  $BucketDirsToSync){
Copy-S3Object -BucketName $BucketName -Key $dirname  -DestinationKey "Done/$dirname"
}
Foreach( $dirname in  $BucketDirsToSync){
Remove-S3Object -BucketName $BucketName -Key $dirname -Force
}
Stop-Transcript
```

The problem is that it can take a long time to complete when a huge amount of files is received. Is there a way to make this script more efficient and handle the files quicker? It seems like it may be possible without using a list but then we would have an issue with duplicate files.

Comment: It depends on what is limiting the speed which is normally due to one of five things 1) Network speed : Use a faster network card or connection 2) Processor Speed : Use a faster computer 3) Disk Storage Time : Use a faster disk.  Disk could be full or fragmented 4) Memory : Programs run much slow when memory usage is high.  Get more memory. 5) Type of Database : Use a better database and make sure database is attached to a server and not a stand along file.

Comment: I would expect an SQS message to contain information on which S3 objects to operate on, and the workers to use this information instead of needed to enumerate the bucket itself.  I'd also expect the worker to remove the one message when it's done, not empty out the queue beforehand.